# How can count length div by id using javascript?

Tags: javascript

When click on `click here` it's still alert `0`.

How can i count length div by id using javascript ?

```js
function swipeDislike() {
  var $photo = $("div.content").find('#photo');
  alert($photo.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="swipeDislike()">
  click here
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="photo">
    DIV content photo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no `div` with class `content` - so, 0 is correct

Comment: @LGSon Length of a jQuery object is the number of elements it selected.

Comment: @Barmar Correct...wanted to know if _what_ meant elements or content.

Comment: I see that now @George  ... so `$('#content #photo')`

Comment: @Durga - but what if that element could exist elsewhere (with dynamic html it can be moved you know) so there could be a use case for looking for it within a particular element, even if it is unique id

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is `id` not `class`.

Change `var $photo = $("div.content").find('#photo');`

To

`var $photo = $("div#content").find('#photo');`

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
function swipeDislike() {
  var $photo = $("div#content").find('#photo');
  alert($photo.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="swipeDislike()">
  click here
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="photo">
    DIV content photo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh , my mistake sir.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo instead of `div.content` use `div#content`

`$("div#content").find('#photo')` instead of `$("div.content").find('#photo')`

But the best way would be to just use `$(“div#content #photo”)`; this way you won't need to use two expensive jQuery calls. Thanks Jaromanda X :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="swipeDislike()">
click here
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="photo">
DIV content photo
</div>
</div>

<script>
 function swipeDislike() {
   var $photo = $("div#content #photo");
   alert($photo.length);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: is `$("div#content #photo")` just the same without two expensive jquery calls :p

Comment: don't take my word for it, I don't know jquery nuance

Comment: No you are right.. I completely overlooked it. Much easier too. Props